# Location Detection from Image Using GPS and Geo-Tagging in Android

Tags: geolocation

I am require to make an **Android Application** that will capture an image of any location from native **camera** and Tell me which location is that in the captured image by using **Geo-Tagging** like service. Now Please **guide me** where to start and where to get the Geo Tagging Api and what to do step wise.
Do I have to implement **Image Recognition** in my app as well or this Processing is already done in the API ?

Please Brief me about this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need image processing. The steps involved:

1) Let the user take a photo

2) When the user submit the image to the server, detect the user's location and submit together to the server.